Video Recorder Component using navigator Web API, facing issues to initiate MediaRecorder ref on initial load but it does gets initiated on onClick
Please find the below JSX for your reference. On initial load when the handleStartRecording(); is called inside useEffect the mediaRecorderRef is null but on onClick event the handleStartRecording() initiates the mediaRecorderRef. Can anybody help me with the code modification such that the mediaRecorderRef initiates on initial render.
const NativeCameraCapture = () => {
    const videoRef: RefObject<HTMLVideoElement> =
      useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
    const mediaRecorderRef = useRef<MediaRecorder | null>(null);
    const [recordedBlobs, setRecordedBlobs] = useState<Blob[]>([]);
    const [stopRecording, setStopRecording] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [recordingState, setRecordingState] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const { state } = useAuthContext();
    const userID = state?.user?.id;

    useEffect(() => {
      const currVideoRef = videoRef.current;
      const constraints = {
        //   audio: true,
        video: { width: 420, height: 550 },
      };

      const startCamera = async () => {
        try {
          await navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then((mediaStream) => {
              if (videoRef.current) {
                videoRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream;
                videoRef.current.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                  videoRef.current?.play();
                };
              }
            });
        } catch (e) {
          console.error("startCamera Error", e);
        }
      };

      startCamera();

      return () => {
        if (currVideoRef && currVideoRef.srcObject) {
          const stream = currVideoRef.srcObject as MediaStream;
          const tracks = stream.getTracks();
          tracks.forEach((track) => {
            track.stop();
          });
        }
      };
    }, []);

    //Upload to supabase
    useEffect(() => {
      const uploadToSupabase = async () => {
        if (recordedBlobs?.length > 0 && stopRecording) {
          const newBlobFile = new File(recordedBlobs, "blobFile", {
            type: "video/mp4",
          });

          const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
            .from("videos")
            .upload(`${userID}/${uuidv4()}.mp4`, newBlobFile);

          console.log("SUPABASE DATA", data);

          setRecordedBlobs([]);
          setStopRecording(false);
        }
      };

      uploadToSupabase();
    }, [recordedBlobs, stopRecording, userID]);

    //Collect Data
    const handleDataAvailable = useCallback((event: any) => {
      if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        setRecordedBlobs((prev: Blob[]) => [...prev, event.data] as Blob[]);
      }
    }, []);

    console.log("videoRef?.current", videoRef?.current);
    console.log(" mediaRecorderRef.current", mediaRecorderRef.current);

    //Start
    const handleStartRecording = () => {
      try {
        if (videoRef?.current && videoRef.current.srcObject) {
          mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(
            videoRef.current.srcObject as MediaStream,
            {
              mimeType: "video/webm",
            }
          );

          mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener(
            "dataavailable",
            handleDataAvailable
          );
          mediaRecorderRef.current.start();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error:", e);
      }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      setRecordingState(true);
      handleStartRecording();
    }, []);

    //Pause
    const handlePauseRecording = () => {
      mediaRecorderRef.current?.pause();
      setRecordingState(false);
    };

    //Resume
    const handleResumeRecording = () => {
      mediaRecorderRef.current?.resume();
      setRecordingState(true);
    };

    //Stop
    const handleStopRecording = () => {
      mediaRecorderRef.current?.stop();
      setStopRecording(true);
      setRecordingState(false);
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="flex justify-center">
          <div className="relative w-fit h-fit">
            <div className="absolute top-[13px] right-[13px]">
              {recordingState === true ? (
                <Icon icon="recording"></Icon>
              ) : recordingState === false ? (
                <Icon icon="resume" stroke="#FF0000"></Icon>
              ) : null}
            </div>
            <video ref={videoRef} className="w-full h-[480px]"></video>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="flex items-center justify-center mt-4">
          {recordingState === true ? (
            <button
              className="bg-[#FBE7AB] py-1 px-3 rounded-3xl flex gap-1 items-center justify-center"
              onClick={handlePauseRecording}
            >
              <Icon icon={"pause"} fill="#000000" />
              {/* {recordingState === "pause" && <Icon icon={"resume"} />} */}
              <p>Pause</p>
            </button>
          ) : recordingState === false ? (
            <button
              className="bg-[#FBE7AB] py-1 px-3 rounded-3xl flex gap-1 items-center justify-center"
              onClick={handleResumeRecording}
            >
              <Icon icon={"resume"} stroke="#000000" />
              <p>Resume</p>
            </button>
          ) : null}
        </div>

        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setRecordingState(true);
            handleStartRecording();
          }}
          className="bg-green-400 w-fit my-3 cursor-pointer"
        >
          Start
        </div>

        <div
          onClick={() => handleStopRecording()}
          className="bg-red-400 w-fit my-3 cursor-pointer"
        >
          STOP
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

export default NativeCameraCapture;

